# Datepicker given a div and input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been able to successfully attach a datepicker to an input field. However, is it possible to also display the datepicker that is attached to the input after clicking the span field?

```
<div class="date_month">
<input class="date" id = "set_date_01" type="text" readonly> 
<span class="date_icon">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I have looked around and could not find a good solution. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this:

```
$('.date_icon').on('click', function() {
    $('#set_date_01').focus();
});
```

But you really should use a `label` with a `for` attribute instead of your span. You wouldn't need js then to achieve this effect and it would be great for accessibility.

For instance:

```
<div class="date_month">
<label for="set_date_01">
    Pick a date
    <input class="date" id="set_date_01" type="text" readonly>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I will definitely use the label method in the future - thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker has an attribute named `buttonImage`:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    buttonImage: "/images/datepicker.gif",
    showOn: "both"
});
```

`showOn` must be set to `button` or `both` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing which datepicker you're using, but most jQuery date pickers will have events that you can trigger manually.  So you would need to capture the click event for that span tag, and fire the datepicker's 'show the datepicker' event.

Here's some documentation describing what I mean when using the jQuery UI built-in datepicker:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show